# BadImageFormatException with SQLite in ASP.NET razor website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlite, razor

I'm trying to create a very simple webshop in Razor with SQLite. Unfortunately, when i trying to create the database (or creating the SQLiteConnection object) it throws a strange System.BadImageFormatException.

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"}    System.BadImageFormatException

My code looks similar as the following:

```
public bool CreateDatabase()
{
try
{
  string db = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/mydb.sqlite");
  SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(db);
  SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source="+ db + ";Version=3;");
  m_dbConnection.Open();

  string sql = "create TABLE cart (UserHash varchar(35), imageid varchar(255), rider varchar(255), competition varchar(255), usagetype varchar(255), retouch varchar(10), blacknwhite varchar(10))";
  SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  return true;
}
catch (Exception)
{
  return false;
}
}
```

This website probably will run on third-party hosting, so it's essential to use a relative path for the sqlite file location, although i couldn't get it work so far.

In db variable, i get the correct App_Data folder location.
I get the exception at new SQLiteConnection. I also tried using the following connectionstring, no luck:

```
"Data Source=|DataDirectory|mydb.sqlite; Version=3;"
```

What am i missing?

Comment: BadImageFormatException happens when your application and your libraries use a different bitness. 64bit vs 32bit. Use the appropriate version of SQLite for the bitness of your app or change the bitness of your app to match the library version used

Comment: Yep, all i had to do is copy the x86 SQLLite.Interop.dll to the Bin folder of my web application, now it works. Thanks! If you write this as an answer, i'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*BadImageFormatException* happens when your application and your libraries use a different bitness. For example, the application is built for AnyCPU (without prefer 32bit) or x64 and your libraries are compiled for 32bit or viceversa.

Usually the solution is very simple. Just copy the appropriate version of SQLite for the bitness of your app to your run folder or change the Target Platform of your app to match the library version used